# Azure Data Factory - Passing lookup value/id into ForEach copy task not working

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to pass the ID from one storage routine into another copy task, which requires a for each to recursively process each ID. I've setup the Lookup ID task, which is working. It's passing these objects into my for each, in which the settings are "sequential" with items set to the following: @activity('LookupUID').output.value

[foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6cwF.png)

In my for each, I have 1 activity to copy data from another API call to an Azure SQL Database. I have a linked service, with a parameter that is being passed. I'm attempting to use a dynamic content operator to pass the current item from the for each into this parameter, which then gets sent to the API call for the ID parameter. When I manually plug in a value here, it works fine. However, trying to pass the value from the for each into this copy task parameter doesn't produce a data row when running the task.

[copy task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZEzF.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDduX.png)

Answer (score 0):

> You must mention the column name along with the current item in copy activity like **`@item().ID`**

**Example**:

1. I have a `lookup` activity to **get the IDs** from a source. Below is the output of the Lookup activity with a list of IDs.

**Lookup Output:**

[image]

2. I am looping these IDs in the `ForEach` activity and passing the **current item** to a variable.

ForEach activity setting: Items-  **`@activity('Lookup1').output.value`**

[image]

3. I have a string variable in which I am passing the current item as below using Set Variable activity.

**`@string(item().ID)`**

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and replace with your column name

@activity('lookup1').output.firstrow.columnname